# How to access more than one button from 1 onClick function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I've made a function, which will be called when a button is clicked. I want to use it for two buttons, but after implementing it, when I click on one button, both get clicked at the same time?

This is the function, which will be called after `onClick` -

```javascript
showMore = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return { showMore: !prevState.showMore };
  });
};
```

This is the condition I've used to call those two buttons (I know, I can do something here to make it just two if conditions rather than 4, suggestions?)

```javascript
if (!this.state.showMore) {
  accounts = take(accounts['demo_accounts'], DEFAULT_NO_OF_ACCOUNTS);
}

if (this.state.showMore) {
  accounts = accountsData['demo_accounts'];
}

if (!this.state.showMore) {
  cardNumbers =
    take(cardNumbers['demo_numbers'], DEFAULT_NO_OF_ACCOUNTS);
}

if (this.state.showMore) {
  cardNumbers = accountsData['demo_numbers'];
}
```

And I am using it for 2 buttons, however, both the buttons are getting clicked at the same time, I know I can use an ID for button, but that doesn't seen to work as well.

To sum it up, two questions basically -

1. How to reduce the 'if' statements?
2. How to stop both the buttons getting clicked?

Comment: What have you tried to differentiate the two buttons? From what I see, two separate buttons, when clicked, do the same thing, so if one is pressed, it is the same as if the other was pressed.  Can you provide more context (i.e. complete functions and react component code) around the second snippet of code, it isn't clear at all what and where they are in relation to any button you speak of.

Answer (score 0):

> How to reduce the 'if' statements?

Just combine the like conditions. Since all your conditions are basically checking the value of `this.state.showMore` you really only need 1 single conditional test.

```js
if (this.state.showMore) {
  accounts = accountsData['demo_accounts'];
  cardNumbers = accountsData['demo_numbers'];
} else {
  accounts = take(accounts['demo_accounts'], DEFAULT_NO_OF_ACCOUNTS);
  cardNumbers =
    take(cardNumbers['demo_numbers'], DEFAULT_NO_OF_ACCOUNTS);
}
```

> How to stop both the buttons getting clicked?

When I want to use a single general click handler across multiple buttons I use a Higher Order Function, which is a function that returns a function. So in this case I create a `clickHandler = id => () => this.setState({ [id]: <value> });`

This callback takes an `id` parameter that is used when attaching the callback to the onClick handler of an element, and it is invoked right away and returns a new function that is actually used as the callback with the `id` saved in the enclosure.

```
<button onClick={this.clickHandler('a')>Button A</button>
<button onClick={this.clickHandler('b')>Button B</button>
```

Here is a codesandbox example of a HOF handler

[image: Edit gallant-pine-vqcmt]

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer, but you can set it so that each button has a different ID and attaches to a different event handler, like so:

```
<button id="btn1">Click me!</button>
<button id="btn2">Me too!</button>
```

Javascript:

```
const button1 = document.getElementById("btn1").addEventHandler('click', function);
const button2 = document.getElementById("btn2").addEventHandler('click', function2);
```

Comment: 1) This is not the recommended way to attach event listeners to React components, React maintains its own synthetic event system
2) This uses two callback functions, OP wants a single click handler

Comment: Thank you- I didn't fully read that the OP was asking for React, my answer works for html. Thank you for the clarification